# Geotools Label location issue with custom Symbol

Tags: java, geotools

We have a Feature Layer having styling with a symbol using some font create by us.
But we need to apply Labels on this following is the result we expected from this:-

[image: Result From Other tool]

and following is the result we have achieve with the `AnchorPoint` ,`Displacement` and `Rotation` :-

[image: Result from geotools]

Code For Label Style:-

```
Rule rule = styleFactory.createRule();
TextSymbolizer textsym = Styling.styleFactory.createTextSymbolizer();
textsym.setLabel(Styling.filterFactory.property("ColumnName"));
StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
textsym.setFill(sb.createFill(Color.black));
AnchorPoint anchorPoint = sb.createAnchorPoint(sb.attributeExpression("the_geom"),
        sb.attributeExpression("the_geom"));
Displacement displacement = sb.createDisplacement(filterFactory.literal(10), filterFactory.literal(4));
PointPlacement pointPlacement = sb.createPointPlacement(anchorPoint,displacement,filterFactory.property("RotationColumn"));
textsym.setLabelPlacement(pointPlacement);  
rule.symbolizers().add(textsym);
```

Comment: please add the code or sld that you are using to create the symbol

Comment: we have added the code to generate Label styling please check updated question.

Comment: now we need to see some example values for ColumnName and RotationColumn

Comment: `ColumnName` have the values for Label like 'BSCE45','BSCe46' and so on and `RotationColumn` could have any value between `0-360`.[Example File](https://www.sendspace.com/file/j1x7ia) in this file any column is `LabelColumn` and `azm` is rotation column please check.

Comment: then what you see looks plausible for those values - why did you think they would be horizontal if you set a rotation?

Comment: i just ask how to do this. if i hasn't set the rotation all the labels came on one single point . i need to place all the labels horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Expression deg2rad = filterFactory.literal(Math.PI / 180);
        Expression angle = filterFactory.multiply(deg2rad,
                filterFactory.subtract(filterFactory.literal(90), filterFactory.property(mplayer.LayerRotation)));
        Expression x = filterFactory.multiply(filterFactory.function("cos", angle),
                filterFactory.literal(intOffset));
        Expression y = filterFactory.multiply(filterFactory.function("sin", angle),
                filterFactory.literal(intOffset));
        Displacement off = sb.createDisplacement(x, y);
```

After this create four rules for each quadrant `0-90` , `90-180`, `180-270` ,`270-360`

```
// For 0-90
AnchorPoint anchorPt = sb.createAnchorPoint(0, 0);
Filter flt =CQL.toFilter(filterFactory.property(LayerRotation) + " <=90");
LabelPlacement pointPlacement = sb.createPointPlacement(anchorPt, off, filterFactory.literal(0));
        textsym1.setLabelPlacement(pointPlacement);
```

above code is same for all the `Quadrants` just u need to change the anchor point for all the quadrants.
For `90-180` anchor point is `AnchorPoint anchorPt = sb.createAnchorPoint(0, 1);`
For `180-270` anchor point is `AnchorPoint anchorPt = sb.createAnchorPoint(1, 1);`
For `270-360` anchor point is `AnchorPoint anchorPt = sb.createAnchorPoint(1, 0);`

@iant please share with your team or propose better idea if any.

Answer (score 0):

I can get closer to what you want with the following code:

```
StyleBuilder builder = new StyleBuilder();
FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
int offset = 10;

TextSymbolizer textSymbolizer = builder.createTextSymbolizer(Color.black, builder.createFont("Arial", 10), "CELL");
Expression deg2rad = ff.literal(Math.PI/180);
Expression angle = ff.multiply(deg2rad, ff.property("azm"));
Expression x = ff.multiply(ff.function("cos", angle),ff.literal(offset));
Expression y = ff.multiply(ff.function("sin", angle),ff.literal(offset));
Displacement off = builder.createDisplacement(x, y);
AnchorPoint anchorPt = builder.createAnchorPoint(0, 0);//centre on point
LabelPlacement pointPlacement = builder.createPointPlacement(anchorPt , off, ff.literal(0));
textSymbolizer.setLabelPlacement(pointPlacement );

Style style = builder.createStyle(textSymbolizer);
//SLDTransformer transformer = new SLDTransformer();
//transformer.setIndentation(4);
//String xml = transformer.transform( style );

//System.out.println(xml);
```

But it only draws the first label because the label placement system considers all labels to be drawn at the same point (I think) and so even if you set the `<VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>` it won't draw them. If this is the case then you should file an [improvement request on the Jira](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/summary) but do check out [this guide](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer) (it's for GeoServer but the same applies to GeoTools).